# Distinct attribute names

Tags: xquery

With XQuery I want to select a special value from every article within a product.

What I currently have:

**Input XML (extract):**

```
<product type="product" id="2246091">
<product type="article">
  <attribute identifier="EXAMPLE1" type="BOOLEAN">0</attribute>
  <attribute identifier="EXAMPLE2" type="BOOLEAN">1</attribute>
</product>
<product type="article">
  <attribute identifier="EXAMPLE1" type="BOOLEAN">1</attribute>
  <attribute identifier="EXAMPLE2" type="BOOLEAN">1</attribute>
</product>
<product type="article">
  <attribute identifier="EXAMPLE1" type="BOOLEAN">0</attribute>
  <attribute identifier="EXAMPLE2" type="BOOLEAN">1</attribute>
</product>
</product>
```

**XQuery:**

```
 for $i in //product
                 [@type = 'product' 
                 and @id = '2246091']
                 //attribute
                 [@type='BOOLEAN' 
                 and @identifier= ('EXAMPLE1', 'EXAMPLE2') ]
 where $i = '1'
 return $i
```

This returns me every `attribute` element from every article under a `product` where the content is '1' and its identifier is EXAMPLE1 or EXAMPLE2.
It could be, that in article 1 there is the same `attribute` identifier (e.g. EXAMPLE1) as in article 2.

**What I get:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<attribute identifier="EXAMPLE2" type="BOOLEAN">1</attribute>
<attribute identifier="EXAMPLE1" type="BOOLEAN">1</attribute>
<attribute identifier="EXAMPLE2" type="BOOLEAN">1</attribute>
<attribute identifier="EXAMPLE2" type="BOOLEAN">1</attribute>
```

I tried to add a distinct-values around my `for` loop, but this will return me only '1'.

**What I would like is to get every attribute only once:**

```
<attribute identifier="EXAMPLE2" type="BOOLEAN">1</attribute>
<attribute identifier="EXAMPLE1" type="BOOLEAN">1</attribute>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with lua? What does the input file look like? Does it have these elements duplicated?

Comment: Yes these elements are existing for every article. For Example 'EXAMPLE1' can be on article 1 and article 2 and set '1' under the same product.

Comment: And you need the attribute elements from all articles because they might have different names and you want all the names?

Comment: Updated the question with correct code snippets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if what you want is to see one `attribute` element for each distinct value of the `identifier` attribute found among the `attribute` elements whose content is 1.  (Or, slightly more challengingly, one `attribute` element for each set of equivalent `attribute` elements, where equivalence is defined by deep-equals().)

The distinct-values() function isn't helping you here, because it coerces any input nodes into simple values (here, 1).

### If matching on the `identifier` attribute suffices

If the `identifier` attribute suffices to establish equivalence among the elements, then something like the following should suffice (not tested):

```
let $ones := //product[@type = 'product' 
                       and @id = '2246091']
             //attribute[@type='BOOLEAN' 
                         and @identifier = 
                         ('EXAMPLE1', 'EXAMPLE2') ],
    $ids := distinct-values($ones/@identifier)
for $id in $ids
return ($ones[@identifier = $id])[1]
```

### If a more general equivalence test is needed

If `@identifier` does not suffice to establish equivalence for your purposes, you will have to do something more complicated; in the general case one way to do it would be to write a function of two arguments (I'll call it `local:equivalent()`) which returns true iff the two arguments are equivalent for your purposes.  Then write a second function to accept a sequence of items and remove duplicates from the sequence (where 'being a duplicate' means 'returning true on `local:equivalent()`).  Something like this might work as a first approximation (not tested):

```
(: dedup#1:  remove duplicates from a sequence :)
declare function local:dedup(
  $items as item()*
) as xs:boolean {
  local:dedup($items, ())
};

(: dedup#2: work through the input sequence one
   by one, removing duplicates and accumulating
   non-duplicates.  Cost is n^2 / 2. :)
declare function local:dedup(
  $in as item()*,
  $out as item()*
) as xs:boolean {
  if (empty($in)) 
  then $out
  else let $car := head($in)
       return if (some $i in $in
                  satisfies
                  local:equivalent($i, $car))
              then local:dedup(tail($in), $out)
              else local:dedup(tail($in), ($car, $out))
};

(: equivalent#2:  true iff arguments are equivalent :)
declare function local:equivalent(
  $x, $y : item()
) as xs:boolean {
  // determine application-specific equivalence
  // however you like ...
  deep-equal($x, $y)
};

(: Now do the work :)
let $ones := //product[@type = 'product' 
                       and @id = '2246091']
             //attribute[@type='BOOLEAN' 
                         and @identifier = 
                         ('EXAMPLE1', 'EXAMPLE2') ]
return local:dedup($ones)
```

Those comfortable with higher-order functions will want to go a step further and remove the dependency on having a function named `local:equivalent` by allowing both `local:dedup` functions to accept an additional argument providing the equivalence function.

Comment: Almost perfect. I added the `text() = '1'` to your last line:
`return ($ones[@identifier = $id and text()='1'])[1]`
Because sometimes the attribute is not filled out!

Comment: Yes; omission of the test against '1' was an oversight.